# Reverse continuous compound interest formula (solve for r)?

Tags: exponentiation

The continuous compound interest formula is pretty simple:

$$
A = P*e^{rt}
$$

But how can I solve for $r$?

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A%3DP*e%5E(r*t)+solve+for+r) introduces this variable $n$ out of thin air, plus imaginary $i$ which I'm not sure is necessary or not if we can add a few more constraints.

Basically, I've got a final amount $A$, an initial principal $P$, an amount of time $t$ and I want to know what the equivalent interest rate is, assuming it was compounded. If "continuous" is too hard to solve for, monthly would also be fine.

Comment: $r=log(A/P)/t$.

Comment: That's natural log, i.e. to base $e$ not base 10.

Comment: @user121049 Ah.. thank you. Couldn't remember how to take down a power :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{A}{P}=e^{rt}$

so 
$\ln(\frac{A}{P})=rt$ which should be easily solved for $r$